# Directus 10 - Autostart Node

Tags: node.js, directus

I am having a hard time finding the location of start.js in the new Directus 10 folder structure. I want to locate start.js which was earlier in Directus 9 located at node_modules/directus/dist/start.js

I want to autostart or keep alive Directus 10 after the server reboot.

Comment: also not working for me anymore , with pm2 , ecosystem.config.js
**code** 
`module.exports = {
 apps: [
  {
   name: 'directus-8055',
   script: 'node_modules/directus/dist/start.js',
  },
 ],
}`

Comment: I got it working. start.js has been moved to different folder node_modules/@directus/api/dist/start.js I also found out it is not efficient way of starting directus instead use npx directus start

Comment: Make sure you have edited .env file with all required details.